# Shrinkwrap not working on half model ( mirrored half )

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm new to Blender coming from Max.
I'm doing retopo on a face that I sculpted on zBrush. The face and the hair
are one object because the model is a manikin so it's solid and the hair style is not symmetrical.
I started modeling half the face and everything was going good, so, after 
I finished, I applied the mirror deformer so I had the full face, and then I started
to work on the hair that is not symmetrical. But the new half face ist not responding to the modifier.
Any idea of what should I do?.

Here is  a pic with the problem , left side ok , right side not wrapping
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the .blend file for review?